# How to profile for one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, filtering, profiler

How can I add a filter which can trace sql statements for a particular table name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296906/log-table-access-using-sql-server-profiler

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't set filter to trace specific table directly.

What you can do is specify a filter for `Text Data`:

> File -> Properties -> Event Selection -> Column Filters -> TextData ->
> Like -> [Table Name]

You may find it important to wrap your table's name with wildcard characters: "%table name%".

Comment: As a complement to the answer, here's how to use multiple filters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366780/890890

Comment: You may find it important to wrap your table's name with wildcard characters: "%table name%".

Answer (score 7):

This is how I could do it....

Choose below events in the profiler:

- `Audit Database Object Access Event`
- `Audit Fulltext`
- `Audit Schema Object Access Event`

Make sure to choose `Text Data`, under columns.

Then under column filters choose:

- `DatabaseID` ---> enter specific databaseID
- `ObjectId` ---> enter specific objectID (select from `sysobjects` for that specific table)
- `ObjectName` ---> enter required tablename