# SQL Server Profiler : How to specify multiple values for "NOT LIKE" column filter

Tags: sql-server, profiler

According to :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175061.aspx
It says that the "NOT LIKE" relational operator :
"Specifies that the trace event data must not be like the text entered. Allows multiple values."

But HOW do you specify multiple values ?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out. After you have typed in one value, press ENTER at the end of the textbox. This causes another textbox to be shown under the current one, into which you can type an additional value.

Comment: thanks, easily explains what the msdn documentation apparently deems unnecessary to include.

Comment: Thanks, this had me scratching my head. Pretty crappy UI design choice there.

Comment: Agree, pretty horrible UI. Had to Google how to do this, it led me here :)

Comment: Still the same in SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just to note, the same works for "LIKE" column filter too.

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky , if you add with enter multiple in the **like area** this will OR them. I usally want AND. In **not like area**  or is great , is any of the values in the rows ignored . So for example I was searching for DELETE statements on a specific table. For this in TextData

```
like ->
     %table_name%

not like ->
     %insert%
     %update%
     %select%
```

With this limiting to only delete . This is not perfect if there is a delete with a select text inside it will not run. Try to filter less and then increase your filter based on your production data.

After this tested with a

```
Begin transaction
delete from table_name where 1=2
rollback
```

all perfect !!! Profiler had my statement on screen

Comment: Interesting, but not an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Note that column filter can be edited only while trace is stopped.