# SQL Server Profiler filtering with two or more values

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-profiler

I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere. I have an SQL server, and monitor it using Profiler sometimes. Filters let me drill down to what I want, but usually that's just one thing. At the moment I want to look at low use/frequency jobs. The easiest way for me to filter out the data I want would be to exclude the two heavy use webapps by their login usernames (since the application for both shows as Apache)

The LoginName column filter allows me to filter with a NOT LIKE option containing two lines, one for each web app, but it seems these are ORed, so I get the data for NOT LIKE user1 OR NOT LIKE user2, i.e. everything, but what I real want is NOT LIKE user1 AND NOT LIKE user2

Right now I profile to a table and filter that way, but is there a way to see a live trace of what I want?

Comment: Consider using an extended event session rather than a Profiler trace; those have no trouble combining and inverting predicates in any desired way. (They're less of a burden on the server as a bonus.) They're still slightly more cumbersome to use than Profiler, but not *much*.

Comment: you can refer this link [How to specify multiple values for “NOT LIKE” column filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366216/sql-server-profiler-how-to-specify-multiple-values-for-not-like-column-filte)